# addClass() during only for some second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After some problems with jquery ui autocomplete, I would like create my autocomplete text, I would like ask you:
Why addClass() is not persistent? Add class persist for few seconds and auto remove.

```
i=0;
$(document).keyup('a', function (e) {
    var keycode;
    if (window.event) keycode = window.event.keyCode;
    else if (e) keycode = e.which;

    if ($('#suggerimenti_ricerca').is(':visible')){
        if(keycode==40){
            i = i+1;
            if(document.getElementById('sugg_ric_'+i) == null){
                i = i-1;
                return;
            }
            $('#sugg_ric_'+i).addClass('sugg_hover');

        }else if(keycode==38){
            i = i-1;
            if(document.getElementById('sugg_ric_'+i) == null){
                i = i+1;
                return;
            }
            $('#sugg_ric_'+i).addClass('sugg_hover');
        }
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/net4fun/QX7nd/1/)

Comment: Why are you passing `'a'` as the first argument of `.keyup()`? Also, jQuery normalises the `event.which` property so you don't need to muck around testing `keyCode`. And why use `getElementById()` on the same element that you then immediately select via jQuery?

Comment: seems you want: `$(document).on('keyup','a', function (e) {...});`

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`addClass` does not auto-remove classes after some delay. I would assume that you're adding a class to an element that is being overwritten.

Comment: thanks for answer. I would like change class "sugg_hover" by up and down arrows to: <div><a id="sugg_ric_1"></><a id="sugg_ric_n"></></div>. I would like that class persist until I recall the function written above. But strangely after two seconds the class auto-remove. why??

Comment: It doesn't auto-remove. I would assume that you're adding a class to an element that is being overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Problem:

```
<input type="text" id="search_box" onkey**up**="compilazione_automatica();" />
```

Resolution:

```
<input type="text" id="search_box" onkey**down**="compilazione_automatica();" />
```

Thanks to all.